# How to call modules using Keras without crashing Tkinter menus?

Tags: python, tkinter, keras

A project I'm working on calls modules in order to generate models in order to predict text. For the duration of these modules being run (longer for generation, obviously), the Tkinter menu in the main program stops working. Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Code isn't really useful, it's just your regular way of loading custom modules through import, then calling with "module.fuction()".

Comment: You would have to run the called modules in a separate thread or separate process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module to run something on a different thread.

1. Import the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module

```py
import threading
```

2. Create a function you want the new thread to run
3. Create a new thread and pass in the function you created

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=function, args=arguments)
```

Where `target` is the function you want to call in this new tread, and `args` are the arguments you need to pass into your function (you can leave `args` out if there are no arguments to pass in)

4. Run the new thread

```py
thread.start()
```

Comment: This seems to work somewhat, but now when the module is run it throws this exception: `File "C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 73, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'` (full exception is much longer, but can't fit in character limit)

Comment: This is the full exception: [link](https://pastebin.com/kFS0SdBd)

Comment: Can you also put the code (on that link) so I can see what caused that error?

Comment: Never mind, I just downgraded tensorflow and that seemed to solve the problem! Thanks for your help!